# SUM Based Off A Criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I SUM "Orders" when there is a value for "Spend" and also the NULL rows that comes after it going from oldest to newest?

Current Output:

```
    Date   |   Product  |   Spend   |  Orders
------------------------------------------------
2017-09-18    Product A     NULL         7
2017-09-11    Product A     NULL         7
2017-09-04    Product A    1000.00      16
2017-08-28    Product A     NULL         7
2017-08-21    Product A    2000.00      35
2017-08-14    Product A    1000.00      20
2017-08-07    Product A     NULL         3
2017-07-31    Product A     NULL         3
2017-07-24    Product A    1000.00      14
```

Desired Output:

```
    Date   |   Product  |   Spend   |  Orders  | SUMMED Orders
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-09-18    Product A     NULL         7          NULL
2017-09-11    Product A     NULL         7          NULL
2017-09-04    Product A    1000.00      16          30 (16 + 7 + 7)
2017-08-28    Product A     NULL         7          NULL
2017-08-21    Product A    2000.00      35          42 (35 + 7)
2017-08-14    Product A    1000.00      20          20 (20)
2017-08-07    Product A     NULL         3          NULL
2017-07-31    Product A     NULL         3          NULL
2017-07-24    Product A    1000.00      14          20 (14 + 3 + 3)
```

I wrote the math expression in the SUMMED Orders column to show how I came up with the new total.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you order by date correctly?

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro I corrected the dates to match. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a group to the rows by counting the number of non-null rows that are older.  You can then use this group to calculate the sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(orders) over (partition by product, grp) as summed_orders
from (select t.*,
             sum( (spend is not null)::int ) over (partition by product order by date asc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

This doesn't remove the first row.  I'm not sure what the logic is for removing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select "date", product, spend, orders, sum(orders) over (order by "date") rt
  from t1
 order by "date" desc , spend nulls first;
```

Comment: It's almost there, but I need to have "rt" reset every time there is a "Spend" value. This "rt" column keeps summing all the way through for each product.

Comment: Ok just an assumption on my part, let me edit and fix that for you

Comment: Should run nicely now, give it a try and let us know.